# Unable to add forward map ...: SERVFAIL

Tags: bind, ddns, dhcpd

DHCPD[4.3.5] error:

> Unable to add forward map from nvhenz710.hen.mentats.us to 172.24.1.31: SERVFAIL

no errs in BIND 9.11.1-P2-RedHat-9.11.1-2.P2.fc26

```
$  groups named dhcpd
named : named dhcpd
dhcpd : dhcpd named

selinux permissive
```

tcpdump looks clean (its talking to bind on same server)

named.conf:

```
//
// named.conf
//

options {
       listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 172.24.251.251;};
       /* listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; }; */
       directory       "/var/named";
       dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
       statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
       memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
       allow-query     { 172.24.0.0/16; 192.168.122.0/24; localnets; };
       allow-update     { 172.24.0.0/16; localnets; };
       recursion yes;

       dnssec-enable yes;
       dnssec-validation yes;
       dnssec-lookaside auto;

       /* Path to ISC DLV key */
       bindkeys-file "/etc/bind/bind.keys.v9_11";

       managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
       forwarders {
               8.8.8.8;
               8.8.4.4;
               };

   disable-empty-zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA";
};


zone "." IN {
       type hint;
       file "named.ca";
};


include "/etc/named.root.key";

//
// Do any local configuration here
//
//
// max logging template
//
//logging {
//category "default" { "debug"; };
//category "general" { "debug"; };
//category "database" { "debug"; };
//category "security" { "debug"; };
//category "config" { "debug"; };
//category "resolver" { "debug"; };
//category "xfer-in" { "debug"; };
//category "xfer-out" { "debug"; };
//category "notify" { "debug"; };
//category "client" { "debug"; };
//category "unmatched" { "debug"; };
//category "network" { "debug"; };
//category "update" { "debug"; };
//category "queries" { "debug"; };
//category "dispatch" { "debug"; };
//category "dnssec" { "debug"; };
//category "lame-servers" { "debug"; };
//channel "debug" {
//file "/var/named/data/nameddbg" versions 2 size 50m;
//print-time yes;
//print-category yes;
//};
//};
//
logging {
category "general" { "debug"; };

category "unmatched" { "debug"; };
category "queries" { "debug"; };
category "resolver" { "debug"; };

category "update" { "debug"; };
category "security" { "debug"; };
channel "debug" {
       syslog;
       print-time yes;
       print-category yes;
       };
};


// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";


#make sure permissions are -rw-r-----. 1 root named
include "/etc/rndc.key";


acl "xfer" {
       /* Deny transfers by default except for the listed hosts.
        * If we have other name servers, place them here.
        */
       172.24.241.241;
       172.24.242.242;
       172.24.243.243;
       172.24.252.252;
};


/*
* DNSSEC Look-aside Validation  
* see https://www.isc.org/downloads/bind/dlv/#dlv_key
*/
trusted-keys {
dlv.isc.org. 257 3 5 "BEAAAAPHMu/5onzrEE7z1egmhg/WPO0+ju
oZrW3euWEn4MxDCE1+lLy2brhQv5rN32RKtMzX6Mj70jdzeND4XknW58
dnJNPCxn8+jAGl2FZLK8t+1uq4W+nnA3qO2+DL+k6BD4mewMLbIYFwe0
PG73Te9fZ2kJb56dhgMde5ymX4BI/oQ+cAK50/xvJv00Frf8kw6ucMTw
FlgPe+jnGxPPEmHAte/URkY62ZfkLoBAADLHQ9IrS2tryAe7mbBZVcOw
IeU/Rw/mRx/vwwMCTgNboMQKtUdvNXDrYJDSHZws3xiRXF1Rf+al9UmZ
fSav/4NWLKjHzpT59k/VStTDN0YUuWrBNh";
};

/*
* You might put in here some ips which are allowed to use the cache or
* recursive queries
*/
acl "trusted" {
       172.24.250.250;
       172.24.251.251;
       172.24.252.252;
       172.24.241.241;
       172.24.242.242;
       172.24.243.243;
       127.0.0.0/8;
       ::1/128;
};


//zone "localhost" IN {
//      type master;
//      file "pri/localhost.zone";
//      notify no;
//};

//zone "127.in-addr.arpa" IN {
//      type master;
//      file "pri/127.zone";
//      notify no;
//};

/*
* Briefly, a zone which has been declared delegation-only will be effectively
* limited to containing NS RRs for subdomains, but no actual data beyond its
* own apex (for example, its SOA RR and apex NS RRset). This can be used to
* filter out "wildcard" or "synthesized" data from NAT boxes or from
* authoritative name servers whose undelegated (in-zone) data is of no
* interest.
* See http://www.isc.org/software/bind/delegation-only for more info
*/

zone "hen.mentats.us." {
       type master;
       file "zones/hen.mentats.us.hosts";
       allow-update  { 172.24.0.0/16; localnets; };
       };      //end hen zone

zone "24.172.in-addr.arpa." {
       type master;
       file "zones/172.24.rev";
       };      // end 172.24/16 zone

zone "122.168.192.in-addr.arpa." {
       type master;
       file "zones/192.168.122.rev";
       };      // end 1.168 zone


controls {
       inet 172.24.251.251 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       inet 172.24.252.252 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       inet 172.24.241.241 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       inet 172.24.242.242 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       inet 172.24.243.243 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       inet 127.0.0.1 allow { any; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
       };
```

named and zones are in a non-default location

```
$ ll -a /var/named/zones/
drwxrwxr-x. 1 named named  166 Sep 17 22:27 ./
drwxr-x---. 1 root  named  148 Sep 16 14:08 ../
-rw-rw-r--. 1 named named 1.8K Sep 16 14:06 172.24.rev
-rw-rw-r--. 1 named named    0 Sep 17 22:27 172.24.rev.jnl
-rw-rw-r--. 1 named named  358 Sep 16 14:06 192.168.122.rev
-rw-rw-r--. 1 named named 2.9K Sep 16 14:06 hen.mentats.us.hosts
-rw-rw-r--. 1 named named    0 Sep 17 21:33 hen.mentats.us.hosts.jnl
```

Any suggestion on how to get more detail on WHY/HOW it is failing?

Is there a BIND logging that I can turn on that I missed

Comment: I am also a little suspicious of the 0 length .jnl files

Comment: It could be that your `jnl` files are out of sync with zone. You should try to stop Bind, then delete `*.jnl` and restart Bind

Comment: Please note that ISC DLV's service has been shut down since early October '17.    You should remove the `dnssec-lookaside auto` line.

Answer (score 3):

it was indeed the jnl files. I had selinux issues earlier and in the process of resolving them it evidently left the empty files. Because of all the queries being logged, and the way I was filtering the journal (using a follow after restart) I missed the complaints at named startup which did not fail the service, just didnt load the zones, thus SERVFAIL.
removingthe jnl files and restarting named, resolved the issues. Next step is enforcing  selinux and crossing my fingers. Thanx to editors that cleaned up my post.